# How can the autocomplete search fragment be visible on a button onclick only?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a map activity. i have added a autocomplete search fragment in the map to search places. I want to show the autocomplete fragment only when my search button is clicked. How to do that? I want the given code inside a button click.

```
 placeAutoComplete = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete);
    placeAutoComplete.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            addMarker(place);
            //Log.d("Maps", "Place selected: " + place.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.d("Maps", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
public void addMarker(Place p){

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    markerOptions.position(p.getLatLng());
    markerOptions.title(p.getName()+"");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.hosp));

    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(p.getLatLng()));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly for your case, Google has a section in the documentation:

> If you want your app to use a different navigational flow (for example, to trigger the autocomplete experience from an icon rather than a search field), your app can launch autocomplete by using an intent.

In this case, you do not have to implement callbacks, please look at [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) page and look for the section `Option 2: Use an intent to launch the autocomplete activity`.

Basically, you have 2 steps, as explained in the documentation:

> 1) Use PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder to create an intent, passing the desired PlaceAutocomplete mode. The intent must call startActivityForResult, passing in a request code that identifies your intent.
>
> 2) Override the onActivityResult callback to receive the selected place.

This code goes into your `onClickListener`:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).build(this);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    // TODO: Handle the error.
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    // TODO: Handle the error.
}
```

Then you override `onActivityResult`, just look up the documentation page, everything is explained there very well.

Comment: Where in map activity, do i need to put this code related to intent?

Comment: @ShrishtiJain you said that you want the autocomplete to appear on button click, so you put the intent inside of your search button `onClickListener`, I mentioned this in the answer. Or as you said: "I want the given code inside a button click." so you put the intent code inside a button click, override `onActivityResult` and handle the result there. Please look at the link that I provided as well.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: I have done this task. Now when i am implementing the interface PlaceSelectedListener and trying to call a method addMarker from the overridden method  onPlaceSelected, It does not take me to that place which i have entered in the search.

Comment: Yes it's working. Thank you but can you help me with this. I want to search the place and locate it on the map.

Comment: @ShrishtiJain That's good, you can retrieve the place that you chose in the autocomplete, you should do it in `onActivityResult` by adding this line `Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);`, and then you can retrieve various information like `place.getLatLng().latitude` or something else. Afterwards, you can put the `place` variable in a field and use it somewhere else. But if the current issue is resolved you should accept the answer and open a new question.